# Update Database Table Column From Another Table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two similar table in my database. I want update my database called qu_time in tbl_quotes from table new_quotes.

I have tried query like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_quotes 
SET qu_time = (SELECT qu_time FROM new_quotes)
```

but I get an error

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Let me know if someone have idea to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: because, `new_quotes ` returns multiple rows

Comment: Sure, change the logic of the subquery such that it always returns one row for each record in `tbl_quotes`.  Sharing some data and logic will increase your chances of getting an answer here.

Comment: my both table have 1127 records. This is problem ? I want update all 1127 records. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have atleast one common column in both tables.

Use that column in the join condition and do the updating..

```
UPDATE tbl_quotes t1
       JOIN new_quotes t2
       ON t1.Id_column = t2.Id_column 
SET    t1.qu_time= t2.qu_time
```

Comment: I have done it...as well I am accepting your answer. Thanks